# How to pass a String array as a binding between two SwiftUI Views?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two SwiftUI views, `ContentView` and `SecondView`. There is a `String` array in `ContentView` that I would like to share with my `SecondView`. The `SecondView` simply needs to show the contents using a `VStack`.

I am trying to achieve this using the `@State` and `Binding` properties as follows. Note that I need to learn how to manually iterate over each item in the `String` array, instead of using something like a `List`.

**My Current Code**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
    var body: some View {
        SecondView<String>(elements: $items)
    }
} 

struct SecondView: View {
    var elements: Binding<[String]>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Compiler errors happen in the next line.
            ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { (v: String) in
                Text(v)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to compile the above code yields in the following errors near `ForEach` in `SecondView`.

```
1. Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Text' to expected argument type '(Binding<[String]>.Element) -> Text'
2. Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Binding<[String]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

I would really appreciate any one's ideas or answers on how I can achieve this. I'm extremely new to SwiftUI and I'm having trouble understanding this concept.

#### --UPDATE--

Thank you @Asperi for the fast response. For anyone finding this in the future, there is a place for `Binding<String>`, just not as the variable's type.

`Binding<String>` must be used when you need a custom initializer for your `struct` (see below).

```swift
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var elements: [String]

    init(_ elements: Binding<[String]>){
        self._elements = elements
    }

    // Hidden implementation details
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is corrected code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
    var body: some View {
        SecondView(elements: $items)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var elements: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { v in
                Text(v)
            }
        }
    }
}
```